# Cannot capture variables in Extension Methods

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I'd like an extension method that returns a lambda to set the given variable. I'm kinda just being lazy, but imo this would clean up my code quite a bit.

Any ideas on why the following code doesn't work? I get the message that float me is not used since it is set by the lambda, but I would like it to capture the float and return a lambda to set it.

```
public static Action<float> setter(this float me)
{
    return x => me = x;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create extension methods with lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852916/how-to-create-extension-methods-with-lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work, because it modifes local variable in lambda - float is value type.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float f = 1;
    f.setter()(4);
    Console.WriteLine(f); // prints 1
}
```

You need ref extension method: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/165 (C# 7.2):

```
public static Action<float> setter(ref this float me)
{
    return x => me = x;
}
```